# Get rid of NaN-, Infinite values in Dataframe using for Random Forest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

For a binary prediction problem I want to do feature selection using RandomForest in a first step. I am looking at mostly categorical data thus I have one-hot encoded all the variables.
To get rid of missing values I have done the following:
`df.dropna()`
When I check again for NaN with `df.isna().sum()`
I still see a number of NaN apparently in some of the columns.

And finally when I run my randonForest with the following code:

```
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
# Train the classifier
regressor.fit(df, dataset_target.values)

# Print the name and gini importance of each feature
for feature in  regressor.feature_importances_:
    print(feature)
```

I get the following error message:
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

I am confused and can't find a solution as I tried to get rid of all NaN, additionally I told to handle infinite values same as NaN with `pd.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True`

thanks, willing for any solution

Answer (score 2):

use
`df.dropna(inplace=True)` for changes to be saved.